# Epimorphisms and monomorphisms in the categories of Hopf algebras

Tags: category-theory, hopf-algebras

From [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82301622.pdf) I learned that in the category $\operatorname{HopfAlg}$ of Hopf algebras over a field $k$ epimorphisms are not necessary surjective and monomorphisms are not necessary injective. Can anybody recommend me a text (or texts) where the properties of this category are discussed in more detail? And the same about the category $\operatorname{FinHopfAlg}$ of finite dimensional Hopf algebras over $k$. I suppose in $\operatorname{FinHopfAlg}$ the same is not true, is it? And, for example, is it true that each morphism $\varphi:H\to G$ in these categories can be represented as a composition
$$
\varphi=\mu\circ\varepsilon,
$$
where $\mu$ is a monomorphism, and $\varepsilon$ and epimorphism?

Comment: I'm not sure about Hopf algebras _per se_ (from the title at least, the paper you linked to looks like a pretty good place to start!) but for context it's worth recalling that not every epimorphism in the category of commutative rings is surjective -- e.g. any localization such as $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ is epi. And localizations still aren't the end of the story. See e.g. [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like) for more discussion or the [Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM) for precise statements.